# Using PHP CURL to push data to save.asp with Request.QueryString duplicates

Tags: php, curl, asp-classic

I am using PHP to send Data to an ASP DBA database file. The real issue is that the `Request.QueryString('data')` seems to append data, rather than use new data in a loop, like it's caching.

## The Code (simplified)

On the PHP side of things:
*This is a loop of 5x*, ProductID will be 001,002,003,004,005

```
$fields = array(
            'OrdersID'  => $orderid, //001,002
            'productID' => $row2['orderprodid']
}

send_data($curl);
```

On the ASP side of things:

```
Response.Write(Request.QueryString("OrdersID")&",")
Response.Write(Request.QueryString("productID"&"||"))
```

## The Result

Loop 1:

> 7777,001

Loop 2:  (why is the first bit of data here? It's a new CURL stream.)

> 7777,001,7777,002

Loop 3:

> 404 - File or directory not found.

## UPDATE

Here is an example of my output data. As you see, there is additional data on the second loop of data! THIS is the problem.

Data String:

```
OrderID=99911250&OrderDate=2013-11-8+03%3A58%3A08+PM&LastName=Lanister&FirstName=J`amie&CompanyName=Lionsport&Email=guest%40user.com&ShipAddress=88+Richway&ShipCity=Casterly&ShipState=California&shipstatecode=California&ShipPostalCode=90210&ShipCountry=United+States&ShipCountryID=226&PhoneNumber=999-000-2342&ShipFax=&ShipContactFirstName=Jamie&ShipContactLastName=Lanister&ShipTaxid=&billcompanyname=Lionsport&billemail=&billaddress=&billcity=&billprovinceid=&billstate=&billstatecode=&billpostalcode=&billcountry=&billcountryid=00&billphonenumber=&billfax=&billcontactfirstname=&billcontactlastname=&billtaxid=&CardNumber=&CardType=&ExpMonth=&ExpYear=&CardVendor=Visa&securitycode=&Comments=&Subtotal=286.0000&Shipping=&Tax=&tax_rate=&pst=&pst_rate=&GrandTotal=286.0000&amount_owing=0&ShipWeight=0&blnShipping=0&Status=0&promo_code=none&promo_desc=none&promo_amount=0&POnumber=0&shipping_company=0&InvoiceNumber=0&DateInvoiced=0&ChequeNumber=0&DistributorOrder=0&blnAccepted=0&blnShipped=0&blnInvoiced=0&blnDelivered=0&blnArchived=1&blnSecondNotice=0&blnCancelled=0&shipping_instructions=0&trans_response_code=1&trans_response=0&trans_payment_url=0&discount_percent=&discount_amount=0&blnoldsystem=0&order_type=nonschedulea&userid=0000000&OrdersID=99942945&productID=2941&Quantity=1&quantity_shipped=1&quantity_shipped_current=0&Name=1&UnitPrice=1&SubTotal=1&Weight=1&blnAccepted=1&blnShipped=0&blnDelivered=0&shipping_company=ANDYSHIP&TrackingNumber=000000000&DateShipped=0&depotid=0&shippingid=0&shipping_sequence=0&carrier_companyid=0&assembly_trans_id=ANDY`
```

Response

```
----------------LOOP 1----------------------------
999429452941
1
1
0
1
1
286.0000, 1
1
0, 1
0, 0
0, 0
0, ANDYSHIP
000000000
0
0
0
0
0
ANDY
------------------LOOP 2----------------------------
999429452941, 2940
1, 1  (SEE THE " ,1" - THIS SHOULD'NT BE HERE)
1, 1
0, 0
1, 1
1, 1
286.0000, 1, 1
1, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0, ANDYSHIP, ANDYSHIP
000000000, 000000000
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
ANDYOrdersID=99942945, ANDY
```

So the problem is my Request data 'grows'

1

1,1

1,1,1

**SOVLED.**
I'm stupid. I was sending the same CURL data on each loop. Your solution worked perfect when I fixed my loop. Thank you....!

Answer (score 1):

Is Curl sending the data in the form of an array? If so you may need to accept the values in ASP Classic as an array and then move through the values as required.

You might find it easier to handle the data in ASP Classic if you send the values in NVP format, e.g.;

```
orderid=7777,productid=001,productid=002,productid=002,productid=003

orderParams = SPLIT(orderParams,",")

IF isArray(orderParams) THEN
Redim Preserve arrOrderParams1(1,1)

For op1 = 0 to UBound(orderParams)
    'Loop through NVPs passed in as orderParams and their values "orderid=7777,productid=001,productid=002,productid=002,productid=003"

    'Split individual NVPs into multi-dimensional array
    arrOrderParams2 = Split(orderParams(op1),"=")
    'productid,001

    IF op1 > 0 THEN
        Redim Preserve arrOrderParams1(1,op1+1)
    END IF

    For op2 = 0 to UBound(arrOrderParams2)
        IF op2 = 0 THEN
            arrOrderParams1(0,op1) = arrOrderParams2(op2)
        ELSE
            arrOrderParams1(1,op1) = arrOrderParams2(op2)
        END IF
    Next

    IF isNumeric(arrOrderParams1(1,op1)) THEN
        ' Do something with the values
        response.write arrOrderParams1(0,op1) & "<Br/>"
        response.write arrOrderParams1(1,op1) & "<Br/>"
    END IF
Next
ELSE
IF orderParams <> "" AND Instr(orderParams,"=") THEN
    Redim Preserve arrOrderParams1(1,1)

    'Split individual NVPs into multi-dimensional array
    arrOrderParams2 = Split(orderParams,"=")
    'productid,001

    IF op1 > 0 THEN
        Redim Preserve arrOrderParams1(1,op1+1)
    END IF

    For op2 = 0 to UBound(arrOrderParams2)
        IF op2 = 0 THEN
            arrOrderParams1(0,op1) = arrOrderParams2(op2)
        ELSE
            arrOrderParams1(1,op1) = arrOrderParams2(op2)
        END IF
    Next
    For op1 = 0 to UBound(orderParams)
        ' Do something with the values
        response.write arrOrderParams1(0,op1) & "<Br/>"
        response.write arrOrderParams1(1,op1) & "<Br/>"
    Next
END IF
END IF
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the data does come across as NVP. You're code is helpful, I will work on building a solution today. The real issue is that the PHP CURL data seems to be appending, instead of being cleared on each push of unique data. Almost like ASP is caching the Reponse data some where?

Comment: To simply the problem, my data comes thru as:
1
1,1
1,1,1